# I accidentally commited my a gmail TokenRepsonse-user file linked to my personal Gmail to internal source control

Tags: gmail

So, I work as a QA UI-Automation developer. We've got a package linked to gmail to pull and examine emails generated from our automated tests, and that email exists as a service. Each test at the moment has it's own inbox, so whenever we make a new test, we have to set up a new email address.

Fast foreward, and I accidentally committed to the TokenResponse-user file for my personal address to our source code. I'm not *too* worried about it, as I've removed permission for the reader service our automation framework utilizes in my gmail account settings, in addition I've got the project lead (who wasn't incredibly happy about it) to completely remove the file from history.

Since the file was out there though, I have to ask, if anyone knows, is there is known way that this file can be used to access my inbox after revoking access to the service?